# Do I have to "Sign In" each time I visit google.com/analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, authentication

I'm already signed in my Gmail account and saved my password. To view my mailbox the only thing I have to do is to visit Gmail.com.

But the problem is with visiting analytics.google.com. Each time after visiting the URL I have to click on "Sign In" and the funny thing is that I don't have to enter my credentials and I'm quickly redirected to analytics control panel. So it sounds like a time-wasting job to click on sign in each time I visit there.

Today I found that by visiting analytics.google.com/web I don't have to click on sign in anymore. But isn't there any way for not clicking sign in when you visit analytics.google.com or googleanalytics.com or google.com/analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's their splash screen, and annoyingly it has always been like that. Unfortunately there is no way to skip it without going directly to the `/web`.

I'd suggest just bookmarking the link to http://www.google.com/analytics/web/, or if you use Chrome, type in the full URL (same as above) and eventually it'll learn to autocomplete to that instead of the splash screen.

Comment: As there's no answer to my question, I have to accept your answer as accepted answer though this is not solving my problem. Thanks MisterPhilip.

Comment: I wish I had a better answer for you too. I am annoyed they do that :(

Answer (score 2):

If you're a Chrome user, there's an extension that automatically bypasses the splash called [Straight to Google Analytics](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/straight-to-google-analyt/obnalgemgaiglcdlkdhnfahhihkiijde). It takes a second or so to redirect, but much better than clicking that Sign On link every time.